# Error with using PHP File in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have the following problem. I have a PHP File, which should give me a JSON Object so I can display it in my HTML File. This works perfectly, I receive a output, which looks like a JSON Object, but although I will post the PHP File here:

```
    <?php
        header('Content-Type: application/json');

        $erg = array (
                "London" => array(
                    "Wetter" => "Regnerisch", 
                    "Grad" => 12
                ),

                "Manchester" => array(
                    "Wetter" =>"Sonnig", 
                    "Grad" => 15
                ),

                "Cambridge"  => array(
                    "Wetter" => "Bewoelkt",
                    "Grad" => 5
                )
        );

        echo json_encode($erg, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); 
?>
```

I have read something about $.ajax, but I don´t know if I can use it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var newHtml;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'Server2.php',
        type: 'get',
        cache:false,
        success: function(json) {
            $.each(json,function(i, item) {
                    newHtml += '<div>' + item.Wetter +  '</div>'
            })
            $('#inhalt').html(newHtml);
        }
    });
});
```

But when I try to display it in the browser, I receive the following error:

[image]

So I want just to display the output of the PHP File in a div, which I insert into my div with the id inhalt in my HTML document.

I appreciate every help from you guys.

Comment: Two ways to solve problem: **1.** Use `dataType: 'json',` in `$.ajax` conf. options. **2.** Use `var jsonObj = JSON.parse(json);` in the success callback and use `jsonObj`.

Comment: Not sure, but remove `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` and keep `echo json_encode($erg);`

Comment: First of all thank you, it helped me a bit, but do you know, why I receive this error message: **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :** in my php File at line 2 ?

Comment: @Tushar - `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` shouldn't cause any issues, I think the  OP's problem is that he is seeing the entire PHP file on the client side...which makes me wonder if he is opening the html file via `http` or `file://`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just tested this code. Try this code for the jQuery part:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var newHtml;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'Server2.php',
        complete: function( json ){
            //$.each( json.responseJSON, function(i, item) {
            //    newHtml += '<div>' + item.Wetter +  '</div>'
            //});

            // Try this for the keys
            for(var key in json.responseJSON) {
                newHtml += '<div>' + key +  '</div>'
            }
            $( '#inhalt' ).html( newHtml );
        }
    });
});
```

**More Info**

if you want to get the key and the `Wetter` key for each location then try this

```
for(var key in json.responseJSON ) {
    var wetter = json.responseJSON[ key ].Wetter,
        grad = json.responseJSON[ key ].Grad;
    // You can now use the wetter and grad vars wherever you want inside this function
    newHtml += '<div>' + key +  '</div>'
}
```

Comment: It worked fine, so now I can handle **item.Wetter** and **item.Grad** but I don´t receive London, Manchester and Cambridge, do you know, how I can handle this problem ?

Comment: Just edited the above code. It should work fine for you.

Comment: You will now `London, Manchester and Cambridge` in your html

Comment: @Philip - The latest update here should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

I see that the ajax response contains the entire PHP file, this means there could one of the two possible issues here -

1. It seems like you're not running the html file via apache. What's the URL in your browser? Does it start with `file://C:/www/html/test.html`, if so you should load that file via Apache, so should be something like `http://localhost/test.html`
2. Apache is not parsing PHP files, in which case you need the php module installed. You might want to install/enable the php module but since you said the response is being received, I'd say you have it installed.

Can you tell me what URL you are typing to access the html page in the browser? In addition please check the *Network* tab in Chrome to see the AJAX call in realtime.

Comment: I run the entire project with xampp, now I receive a output with **item.Wetter** and **item.Grad**, but I don´t get  London, Manchester and Cambridge, do you know, how I can handle this problem ?

Comment: @Philip - When you open the HTML file in your browser, whats the URL?

Comment: @Philip, your php is good but you'll have to change your javascript for you to get the correct `London, Manchester and Cambridge` response and the html.

Comment: @Philip - Please check the response that you receive on the client side. You can see this in the network tab of the chrome browser. This will give us the exact response that you get. I think the JSON is in the raw format and not parsed by jQuery. Check my updated answer.

Comment: @AbijeetPatro thank you for the help, so now I have learned something !